# Read more + ellipsis (...) in React for dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: html, css, reactjs, npm, ellipsis

Is there a good way to limit the # of lines of html grabbed with dangerouslySetInnerHTML and generate a '... Read More' expander for it for a React app?

I've tried using react-lines-ellipsis but unfortunately the 'text' property doesn't work with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: Please provide a working code example of what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

try this , hope this will help

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

 p{
           max-width: 250px;
            display: -webkit-box;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```